# Serialize Array without root element

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, serialization

I'm trying to get to this result while serializing XML

```
<Test>
  <Category>
    <FileName>C:\test.txt</FileName>
    <!-- Note that here this is an array of a simple class with two fields 
         without root -->
    <Prop1>1</Prop1>
    <Prop2>2</Prop2>

    <Prop1>4</Prop1>
    <Prop2>5</Prop2>
    <!-- End array -->
  </Category>
</Test>
```

I already try different things like this

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Test")]
public class Test
{
    [XmlElement("Category")]
    public List<Category> Category= new List<Category>();
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Category")]
public class Category
{
    [XmlElement("FileName")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Property")]
    public List<Property> Properties = new List<Property>();
}

[Serializable]
public class Property
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

But I still get this output:

```
<Test>
  <Category>
    <FileName>C:\test.txt</FileName>
    <Property>
      <Prop1>1</Prop1>
      <Prop2>2</Prop2>
    </Property>
    <Property>
      <Prop1>4</Prop1>
      <Prop2>5</Prop2>
    </Property>
  </Category>
</Test>
```

How can I remove the Property tag ??
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The XML your are trying to achieve seems pretty ambiguous to me. Having two child nodes with the same name at the same level doesn't look correct.

Comment: First thanks Yads for your reply
I get this file from an external source and I agree with you that it's not a good xml file but as you can imagine we already ask to the editor of the faulty source to correct their output...

Answer (score 6):

In case if you really need the exact output, as specified above, you can use workaround like this:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class Test {
    public List<Category> Category;
}

[Serializable]
public partial class Category {
    [XmlElement("FileName")]
    public string FileName;

    [XmlElement("Prop1")]
    [XmlElement("Prop2")]
    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("propName")]
    public string[] Properties;

    [XmlIgnore]
    public PropName[] propName;
}

public enum PropName {
    Prop1,
    Prop2,
}
```

Comment: Andrey
I want to thank you you for this workaround 
I Implement it and it does the stuff I knwo that it's not a clean solution but I will use time the Xml Source editor correct their output
Thansk again 1000 times

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible without making things complex. One option is to implement `IXmlSerializable`, which is *hard* to get 100% right. You *might* also be able to so it by creating two subtypes, using the type-based versions of `[XmlArrayItem]`, and hacking the model to pieces. Frankly I don't think that is worth it either.

My personal preference here would be to either choose a different layout, or use LINQ-to-XML. This is not a good it for `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: Thanks Marc for your reply I planned to implement an IXmlSerializable solution but finally the workaround with the XmlChoiceIdentifier works well
Thanks again for your reply

Comment: It is possible, and not difficult - see the accepted answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006482/c-sharp-xml-serialization-disable-rendering-root-element-of-array