# How do I get XmlSerializer to not serialize list container tags?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have a simple object graph that I would like to serialize, I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem.  Here it is:

```
   [XmlRoot]
    public partial class MyData
    {

        private List<MyDatum> itemsField;

        public MyData()
        {
            this.anyAttrField = new List<System.Xml.XmlAttribute>();
            this.itemsField = new List<MyDatum>();
        }

        [XmlElement(Type = typeof(MyDatum))]
        public List<MyDatum> Items
        {
            get
            {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

This produces the following XML:

```
<MyData>
    <Items>
        <MyDatum/>
        <MyDatum/>
        ...
    </items>
</MyData>
```

I would like to remove the "Items" container tag to produce this instead:

```
<MyData>
    <MyDatum/>
    <MyDatum/>
    ...
</MyData>
```

I've tried all kinds of solutions, but can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Similar question & answer for arrays: [XML Serialization - Disable rendering root element of array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2006482/3744182).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Specify an element name in your [`[XmlElement]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[XmlElement("MyDatum", Type = typeof(MyDatum))]
public List<MyDatum> Items {
    // ...
}
```

According to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/06/12/customizing-the-xml-for-collections-with-xmlserializer-and-datacontractserializer.aspx) on MSDN, this will remove the wrapper element around serialized items.

Comment: The article is correct; that will indeed remove the wrapper element. The `Type = typeof(...)` is redundant but harmless, btw.

Comment: The syntax is counter-intuitive since "Items" is a collection of "MyDatum" and not a single object "MyDatum".  I never have guessed this as a possible solution in my experiments.  I guess you can say "If it doesn't work then go against your intuition."

Comment: Confirmed as still working in ASP.NET Core Web API serialization