# How do I deserialize a list from xml without the plural parent element?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I would like to deserialize a HTML table into an object. But with the following code, it expects to see `<Rows>` as the parent of `<tr>`'s and `<Cells>` as the parent of `<td>`'s. I want to keep this class structure. Am I missing any attribute declaration?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>

public class Table
{
    [XmlArrayItem("tr")]
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    [XmlArrayItem("td")]
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}

public class Cell
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get XmlSerializer to not serialize container tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199738/how-do-i-get-xmlserializer-to-not-serialize-container-tags)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the attributes as shown below. Note that you'll have to change the type of `Value` on the `Cell` class from `object` to `string`.

```
[XmlRoot("table")]
public class Table
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(Row), ElementName = "tr")]
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
}

public class Row
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(Cell), ElementName = "td")]
    public List<Cell> Cells { get; set; }
}

public class Cell
{
    [XmlText(typeof(string))]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```