# XML Deserialization returns empty array

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

yet another XML Deserialization question.

I have checked several other threads and tried most of the solutions there, but to no avail.
The XML I receive can't be modded (or at least not easily) here it is:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> 
<ActueleVertrekTijden>
    <VertrekkendeTrein>
        <RitNummer>37047</RitNummer>
        <VertrekTijd>2012-11-13T15:40:00+0100</VertrekTijd>
        <EindBestemming>Sneek</EindBestemming>
        <TreinSoort>Stoptrein</TreinSoort>
        <Vervoerder>Arriva</Vervoerder>
        <VertrekSpoor wijziging=\"false\">3</VertrekSpoor>
    </VertrekkendeTrein>
    <VertrekkendeTrein>
        <RitNummer>10558</RitNummer>
        <VertrekTijd>2012-11-13T15:46:00+0100</VertrekTijd>
        <EindBestemming>Rotterdam Centraal</EindBestemming>
        <TreinSoort>Intercity</TreinSoort>
        <RouteTekst>Heerenveen, Steenwijk, Utrecht C</RouteTekst>
        <Vervoerder>NS</Vervoerder>
        <VertrekSpoor wijziging=\"false\">4</VertrekSpoor>
    </VertrekkendeTrein>
    <VertrekkendeTrein>
        <RitNummer>37349</RitNummer>
        <VertrekTijd>2012-11-13T15:59:00+0100</VertrekTijd>
        <EindBestemming>Groningen</EindBestemming>
        <TreinSoort>Sneltrein</TreinSoort>
        <RouteTekst>Buitenpost</RouteTekst>
        <Vervoerder>Arriva</Vervoerder>
        <VertrekSpoor wijziging=\"false\">5b</VertrekSpoor>
    </VertrekkendeTrein>
</ActueleVertrekTijden>
```

There are more  elements (always a minumum of 10)

Now these are the classes I am deserializing too:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot(ElementName="ActueleVertrekTijden", DataType="VertrekkendeTrein", IsNullable=false)]
public class ActueleVertrekTijden
{
    [XmlArray("ActueleVertrekTijden")]
    public VertrekkendeTrein[] VertrekLijst { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class VertrekkendeTrein
{
    [XmlElement("RitNummer")]
    public string RitNummer { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("VertrekTijd")]
    public string VertrekTijd { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("EindBestemming")]
    public string EindBestemming { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Vervoerder")]
    public string Vervoerder { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("VertrekSpoor")]
    public string VertrekSpoor { get; set; }
}
```

I omitted the others for the time being. The XmlRoot part I added because I got a "xmlsn="-error. So had to set the XmlRoot.

Now the Deserializer:

```
        public ActueleVertrekTijden Deserialize<ActueleVertrekTijden>(string s)
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ActueleVertrekTijden));
        ActueleVertrekTijden list = (ActueleVertrekTijden)ser.Deserialize(new StringReader(s));

        return list;
    }
```

It does return a ActueleVertrekTijden class but the VertrekLijst array remains null

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I don't think you want to set the `DataType` property of `XmlRoot` to that. Can you try only setting the `ElementName`? I don't think it will necessarily fix it, but just noticed it.

Comment: When I have issues trying to deserialize external XML, I actually try to serialize my class representations of it then compare it with the external XML I'm receiving. Often times there's a minor mixup or oversight/forgetfulness with how the .NET `XmlSerializer` works. Try creating a sample `ActueleVertrekTijden` with data with your application, serialize it to XML and compare its differences with your source XML that you're trying to deserialize.

Comment: That's a good idea (Now why didn't I think of that myself).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to omit the wrapper namespace, because your array elements are appearing directly below the container `ActueleVertrekTijden` class, without any collection `wrapper` element. i.e. change

```
 [XmlArray("ActueleVertrekTijden")]
 public VertrekkendeTrein[] VertrekLijst { get; set; }
```

to

```
 [XmlElement("VertrekkendeTrein")]
 public VertrekkendeTrein[] VertrekLijst { get; set; }
```

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199738/how-do-i-get-xmlserializer-to-not-serialize-container-tags)

Comment: It worked, thanks. 

Like mentioned in the other thread: "How counter intuitive!" Wouldn't have figured this out myself very fast (perhaps after trial and error testing :P)