# How to serialize a nested list in c# into XML without specifying a list element?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have got two classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string FooName{get;set;}
    public List<Bar> Bars{get;set;}
}

public class Bar
{
    public string BarName{get;set;}
}
```

If I serialize this using the XML parser I come up with:

```
<Foo>
    <FooName>ExampleFooName</FooName>
    <Bars>
        <Bar>
             <BarName>ExampleBarName</BarName>
        </Bar>
        <Bar>
             <BarName>AnotherExampleBarName</BarName>
        </Bar>
    </Bars>
<Foo>
```

Is there any way to receive this as the result:

```
<Foo>
    <FooName>ExampleFooName</FooName>

    <Bar>
         <BarName>ExampleBarName</BarName>
    </Bar>
    <Bar>
         <BarName>AnotherExampleBarName</BarName>
    </Bar>
<Foo>
```

I am looking to either restructure the Foo and Bar classes, or pass in some parameter to the XMLSerializer to receive the result. I really want to avoid writing my own XML parser.

Comment: What did the `Bars` node do to make you reject it?  Now `Bars` is sad. :(  `Bars` wants to know if you'd reconsider.  `Bars` really wants to make this work out with you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get XmlSerializer to not serialize container tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199738/how-do-i-get-xmlserializer-to-not-serialize-container-tags)

Comment: Customer wont let me use Bars :( I'm going over that other answer now

Comment: `Bars` is really sorry to hear that.  You've made `Bars` very angry and now `Bars` is out to get you.  Your code better watch its back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Foo
{
    public string FooName{get;set;}
    [XmlElement("Bar")]
    public List<Bar> Bars{get;set;}
}
```