# Serialization of list inside parent node (flattening of collection)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, collections

I have to generate an XML structured like this (using .NET serialization):

```
<Person>
   <Name>John</John>
   <Address>Address1</Address>
   <Address>Address2</Address>
   <Address>Address3</Address>
</Person>
```

Currently, I have a `class Person` with its name a `List<string> Addresses` inside.

I think the `XmlSerializer` will create by default an `<Addresses>` node that holds every address as a child element, so I would get, instead:

```
<Person>
   <Name>John</John>
   <Addresses>           
      <Address>Address1</Address>
      <Address>Address2</Address>
      <Address>Address3</Address>
   </Addresses>
</Person>
```

That **is not** what I need.

My question is, is it possible to flatten all the addresses inside `<Person>`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199738/how-do-i-get-xmlserializer-to-not-serialize-container-tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use XmlElement instead of XmlArray like code below.  The XmlArray adds an extra layer of tags.

```
    [XmlRoot("Person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string name {get; set;}
        [XmlElement("Address")]
        public string[] address {get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: Is this format deserializable? I mean, how does the serializer know that they are elements of a collection?

Comment: By string[] type which is an array.