# Xml Serialization - Render list of objects directly under Root - Xml - Element

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, xml-serialization

The following model class `serializes` to

```
    [XmlRoot]
    public class A
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Period { get; set; }

        public List<C> B { get; set; }

    }

<?xml version=1.0>
<A Period="Today">
 <B>
    <C>
    </C>
    <C>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

Now, I dont want that `<B>` (List of objects should directly be listed under `XmlRoot`)

The resulting XML should look like,

```
<A Period="Today">
  <C>
  </C>
  <C>
  </C>
</A>
```

Any ideas how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the list as an XML element. This will force the rendering of only its elements:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class A
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Period { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("C")]
    public List<C> B { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: This still gives me C node under B node. I don't want B node at all.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed., I read your question wrong the first time. Updated.

Comment: Just curious: Can you tell me from where did you read or know this ? Any references to further dig in to this info please..

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed., I've recently had the same problem, that's why I remembered it. I've searched for question that solved the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006482/c-sharp-xml-serialization-disable-rendering-root-element-of-array. Check out the attributes listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization(v=vs.110).aspx. It might come in handy next time. :)