# C# XML Serialization removing wrapper element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I wrote because I have problem with XmlSerializer. I want XML in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootXML>
    <e-Invoice>
      <Version>1.03</Version>
    </e-Invoice>
    <TradeInvoice>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Value>100</Value>
    </TradeInvoice>
    <e-Invoice>
      <Version>1.03</Version>
    </e-Invoice>
    <TradeInvoice>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Value>200</Value>
    </TradeInvoice>
    <e-Invoice>
        <Version>1.03</Version>
    </e-Invoice>
    <TradeInvoice>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <Value>300</Value>
    </TradeInvoice>
</RootXML>
```

So I created the following classes.

```
[XmlRoot("RootXML")]
public class Root
{
    public Root()
    {
        RootBodies = new List<RootBody>();
    }

    [XmlElement("e-Invoice")]
    public List<RootBody> RootBodies { get; set; }
}

public class RootBody
{
    public RootBody()
    {
        TradeInvoice = new TradeInvoice();
        EInvoiceInfo = new Version(); ;
    }

    [XmlElement("e-Invoice")]
    public Version EInvoiceInfo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TradeInvoice")]
    public TradeInvoice TradeInvoice { get; set; }
}

public class Version
{
    [XmlElement("Version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

public class TradeInvoice
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have problem with removing wraper Elements (remove RootBody). I read similar topic like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006482/xml-serialization-disable-rendering-root-element-of-array). But it does not solve my problem.

Comment: The XML you are aiming for is not very well designed. If `e-Invoice` and `TradeInvoice` belong together (which they apparently do), they should be serialized together (wrapped).

Comment: I agree Manfred, relying on a property being located directly after another and thus concluding they belong together isn´t a good idea. Instead mark also in the xml that they belong to a single instance of your type. Or do you have an external schema that forces you to format the xml this way?

Comment: I don't created this XML, this xml created outer company, my client.

Comment: @Peter I'll put together an example how this can be achieved - it won't be pretty but it should work (one-way).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the actual explanation, let me point out a couple of very important things:

- This XML is not very well designed and will cause a lot of other problems along the line (I'm guessing it is actually a lot more complicated than this).
- The naming convention is inconsistent (`e-Invoice` and `TradeInvoce`)
- The version number looks out of place, make sure this is really what they (whoever told you to do this) want before investing additional time.
- This XML defines **no** [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) (and probably doesn't have an [XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_(W3C)) or [DTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition) either)
- Take a look at [Google's XML design guidelines](https://google.github.io/styleguide/xmlstyle.html). You'll realize there is a lot of room for improvement.

**There are a lot of different ways to do this, this is just one of them. I recommend you instead take it up with whoever is responsible for this design and try to change their mind.**

Since you want to serialize `e-Invoice` and `TradeInvoce` without a wrapper element but still keep the order of elements (because they belong together) you need to make sure they have a common base class so they can be serialized from the same collection.

This abstract `Invoice` class simply tells the serializer which classes should be included during serialization via the `XmlInclude` attribute.

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(EInvoice))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(TradeInvoice))]
public abstract class Invoice
{
}
```

Your actual classes will be mostly unchanged

```
[XmlRoot("e-Invoice")]
public class EInvoice : Invoice
{
    [XmlElement("Version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("TradeInvoice")]
public class TradeInvoice : Invoice
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Your data class doesn't need any XML-related Attributes anymore because as it is now, it can't be serialized into that format directly.

```
public class InvoicePair
{
    public InvoicePair(EInvoice eInvoice, TradeInvoice tradeInvoice)
    {
        TradeInvoice = tradeInvoice;
        EInvoiceInfo = eInvoice;
    }

    public EInvoice EInvoiceInfo { get; set; }

    public TradeInvoice TradeInvoice { get; set; }
}
```

Your `Root` class has to be simplified a bit. Since we want `EInvoce` and `TradeInvoice` Elements on the same level but mixed together, we need to put them in the same collection. The `XmlElement` attributes will tell the serializer how to handle elements of different types without relying on the `xsi:type` attribute.

```
[XmlRoot("RootXML")]
public class Root
{
    public Root()
    {
        RootBodies = new List<Invoice>();
    }

    [XmlElement(Type = typeof(EInvoice), ElementName = "e-Invoice")]
    [XmlElement(Type = typeof(TradeInvoice), ElementName = "TradeInvoice")]
    public List<Invoice> RootBodies { get; set; }
}
```

Serialization is quite straight-forward at this point. Simply add all elements to the collection of elements one after another:

```
public static void Serialize(IEnumerable<InvoicePair> invoices, Stream stream)
{
    Root root = new Root();
    foreach (var invoice in invoices)
    {
        root.RootBodies.Add(invoice.EInvoiceInfo);
        root.RootBodies.Add(invoice.TradeInvoice);
    }

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
    serializer.Serialize(stream, root);
}
```

Deserialization isn't very hard either, but very prone to erros and makes a lot of assumptions:

```
public static IEnumerable<InvoicePair> Deserialize(Stream stream)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
    Root root = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as Root;

    for (int i = 0; i < root.RootBodies.Count; i += 2)
    {
        yield return new InvoicePair(
            (EInvoice) root.RootBodies[i], 
            (TradeInvoice) root.RootBodies[i+1]
        );
    }
}
```

[Here is a working Demo Fiddle, that outputs the XML](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/AhJrmJ)

Comment: I'm really grateful for your help.I joined your code with my modifications to my project. Your solution works.