# How to serialize List<T> in c# without the ArrayOf wrapper?

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I'm attempting to serialize a `List<T>` of some custom classes with:

```
List<T> l = new List<T>();
...
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(l.GetType());
serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
```

And it outputs:

```
<ArrayOfT>
    <T>
        ...
    </T>
    <T>
        ...
    </T>
</ArrayOfT>
```

How do I get the same thing, but without the `ArrayOfT` elements, so it would look like:

```
<T>
    ...
</T>
<T>
    ...
</T>
```

I'm attempting to do this because it's happening in a wrapper class so my actual output is coming in the format of:

```
<PropertyName>
    <ArrayOfT>
        <T>
            ...
        </T>
        <T>
            ...
        </T>
    </ArrayOfT>
</PropertyName>
```

And the `ArrayOfT` element is redundant (logically it would have the same name as `PropertyName`.)

Comment: Use the `[XmlElement("T")]` attribute if `l` is a property in a class.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I'm trying to completely remove the `ArrayOfT` element, not rename it, also `l` is not a property, it is a variable within an implementation of `IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)` which is in the class which makes up the property.

Comment: Couldn't you just loop over the list?

Comment: @juharr Apparently so, I'm chalking this up to my unfamiliarity with the XmlSerializer, if you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML Serialization - Disable rendering root element of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006482/xml-serialization-disable-rendering-root-element-of-array)

Comment: When serializing the `List<T>` as the root object you cannot eliminate the outer `</ArrayOfT>` because a well-formed XML document must have one and only one [root elemnent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element).  When the `List<T>` is a nested member in some containing type then [XML Serialization - Disable rendering root element of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006482/xml-serialization-disable-rendering-root-element-of-array) is the answer and this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this approach perhaps:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(l.GetType());
foreach (T item in list)
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
}
```

This way you are serializing the items but not the outer object.

Comment: This is correct but while I voted it up I'm not marking it as accepted yet just because @juharr mentioned it first in a comment and I want to give him time to submit it as an answer, I'll check back tomorrow and if he hasn't posted it I'll accept this.