# C# Xml Serializer take only children from parent and save to Collection

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, .net-6.0

**Hi all,**
I have a problem with my xml model. I want to get the child nodes of a parent node and then save the children in a collection.
Is there any way to ignore the node "C" and take only the child nodes? I dont want to have a class called "C" with "D" children.

The A node is not the root of my file.

I use the XmlSerializer from Microsoft to deserialize my model.

Thanks in advance!

```
<A>
    <B>
        <C>
            <D>
                <E/>
            </D>
            <D>
                <E/>
            </D>
        </C>
    </B>
</A>

[XmlRoot("A")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement("B")]
    public B BNode {get;set;}
}

public class B 
{
    [XmlArray("C")]
    public D[] DNodes {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Is A the top node in your document?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006482/xml-serialization-disable-rendering-root-element-of-array

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the A node is the document root this should show how to proceed;

```
    B[] myArray=new B[]{new B("Hello"),new B("World")};
    XmlRootAttribute  root = new XmlRootAttribute ();
    root.ElementName="A";
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(B[]),root);
    var outStream = new StringWriter();
    ser.Serialize(outStream,myArray);
    var xmlText = outStream.ToString();
    Console.Write(xmlText);
    Console.WriteLine();
    TextReader sr = new StringReader(xmlText);
    B[] result = (B[])ser.Deserialize(sr);
```

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GE4uFJ)

For A being child node of some other node use `[XmlArray(ElementName="A")]` instead of `[XmlArrayItem("B")]`.
[fiddle for child node](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6m8iA1)

Comment: The A node is not my root element. It is somewhere in between

Comment: @zTim then just decorate the Array with the XmlArray attribute.  (see edit for new fiddle)

Comment: i dont know why it doesnt work for me. (see edit in question)

Comment: seems like the XmlArray attribute doesnt work. Because if i change it to XmlElement, the object properly filled

Comment: What happens when you use XmlArray attribute?  It seems to work for me; https://dotnetfiddle.net/eiKzaG